# Is it possible to omit a Tensorflow scalar summary dependant on its value?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I build summary ops and add them to collections, then always evaluate the summary collection as part of the `sess.run` call during training/validation.

However, there are some cases where the value is `nan`, and it makes the Tensorboard graphs go bad. (triangles instead of data points, and the smoothing doesn't work with a nan value in between).

Is there a way to omit a particular summary from the collection,  dependant on the value being valid? I could replace the nan value with a zero or similar, but any artificially chosen value would pollute the true reported statistics.

I add the summaries like this:
`tf.summary.scalar('scc_precision_test', precision_test, [Constants.TEST_SUMMARIES])`

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the value of your summary before writing it to the `FileWriter`:

```
prec_test = tf.summary.scalar('scc_precision_test', precision_test,
                              [Constants.TEST_SUMMARIES])
# ... 
..., prec_test_sum = sess.run([..., prec_test], ...)
prec_test_sum = tf.Summary().FromString(prec_test_sum)
if np.isfinite(prec_test_sum.value[0].simple_value):
    writer.add_summary(prec_test_sum.SerializeToString(), global_step=...)
```

If you have multiple summaries merged into a single `tf.Summary` object (e.g. made with `tf.summary.merge`/`tf.summary.merge_all`), then you would have to filter the `value` field:

```
prec_test = tf.summary.scalar('scc_precision_test', precision_test,
                              [Constants.TEST_SUMMARIES])
merged = tf.summary.merge_all(key=Constants.TEST_SUMMARIES)
# ... 
..., merged_sum = sess.run([..., merged], ...)
merged_sum = tf.Summary().FromString(merged_sum)
# Reversed traversal to be able to delete elements while iterating correctly
for i, value in reversed(list(enumerate(merged_sum.value))):
    # Discard summary if is scalar and not finite
    if value.WhichOneof('value') == 'simple_value' and not np.isfinite(value.simple_value):
        del merged_sum[i]
# Write all valid summaries
writer.add_summary(merged_sum.SerializeToString(), global_step=...)
```

Comment: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'values'. merged_sum is just a bytes-array?

Comment: @AshHall Right, forgot the return value is the serialized byte array, not the protobuf object itself...